# Using one array filter instead of multiple ones

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

Is there a way to merge all these filters into one? Or another way to make it more effective? Or just use for loop?

```
 driving += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'driving').length;
    breathWork += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'breath work').length;
    meditation += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'meditation').length;
    cooking += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'cooking').length;
    walking += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'walking').length;
    other += value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND && obj.data.practice === 'other').length;
```

They look to me very redudant.

Comment: Why do you have 6 different variables? Isn't that redundant in the first place?

Comment: I need to know the count of each "obj.data.practice" separatly.

Comment: Okay. It would have been better if you posted example of `obj` itself. The variables wouldn't be required at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're looping 6 times over the same array. You can reduce the runtime with a simple for-loop or reduce:

```
const counts = value.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.type !== CalendarEventType.MIND) return acc;
  acc[el.data.practice] = (acc[el.data.practice] ?? 0) + 1
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Example:

```js
const CalendarEventType = {
  MIND: 1,
  OTHER: 2
};

const value = [
  {type: CalendarEventType.MIND, data: { practice: 'driving' } },
  {type: CalendarEventType.MIND, data: { practice: 'breath work' } },
  {type: CalendarEventType.OTHER, data: { practice: 'breath work' } },
  {type: CalendarEventType.MIND, data: { practice: 'other' } },
  {type: CalendarEventType.MIND, data: { practice: 'other' } },
  {type: CalendarEventType.OTHER, data: { practice: 'other' } },
];

const counts = value.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.type !== CalendarEventType.MIND) return acc;
  acc[el.data.practice] = (acc[el.data.practice] ?? 0) + 1
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: This is really good.

Comment: @Donut Thank you.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of values and use a single filter.

```
const
    practices = ['driving', 'breath work', 'meditation', 'cooking', 'walking', 'other'];
    filter = ({ type, data: { practice } }) => type === CalendarEventType.MIND && practices.includes(practice),
    result = value.filter(filter),
    count = values.reduce((sum, o) => sum + filter(o), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to group by `data.practice`. Since there's no native  "group by" function, you could implement it yourself (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511)), or you could use a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy).

Example, using Lodash's `groupBy`:

```
const filteredItems = value.filter((obj) => obj.type === CalendarEventType.MIND);
const groupedItems = groupBy(filteredItems, obj => obj.data.practice);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with `groupedItems`, e.g.:

```
driving += groupedItems['driving'] ? groupedItems['driving'].length : 0;
```

Note that if a given value for `data.practice` is not represented in `filteredItems`, then that key won't be present in `groupedItems` - hence the need to check for that key.